# Animate several progress bar with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to write js to animate several bootstrap progress bar based on thier width. I write simple code but its not working, probably because its takes value of first DOM element with class progress bar. Can you please suggest me how can i resolve this issue ? Thank you very much :)

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<h5>Zapotrzebowanie na kawę</h5>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
      70% Complete (danger)
    </div>
  </div>

  <h5>J. Angielski</h5>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
      C1 (danger)
    </div>
  </div>
    <h5>j. Niemiecki</h5>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:60%">
      A2
    </div>
  </div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
var cWidth = $('.progress-bar').css("width")
$(".progress-bar").animate({width: cWidth}, 1500)
});
```

**EDIT**
So i manage to resolve problem  by using modified code provided my @streetlamp

Yet im not quite satisfied with it, cause it a little freeze at the bening. Not smooth enough. Do you have some suggestion ?

```
$(".progress-bar").css("width", "0px")
$(function() {
    $(".progress-bar").each(function() {
        var finalWidth = parseInt($(this).attr("aria-valuenow"));
        $(this).css("width", "0px").animate({width: finalWidth+"%"}, 1000);
    });
});
```

Thank you for all help so far .

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do, are you simply trying to get all of the bars animated to full width at once?

Comment: I try to get all bars animated to specific width at once.

Comment: Like [this](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/EVdRwj?editors=100)?

Comment: Yes but with ecpetion that it should start from 0 and have animation effect to specific value . So from 0 to 60 , 0  to 50 etc.

Comment: All to a specific value or each to it's own value?

Comment: Each one to specific value, based on input : Its basically saying skill lvl in % . So Skill 1 X , skill 2 y , skill 3 z  . Animation from 0 to this specific number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can target each `.progress-bar` by `eq()`

Code:

```
$(function () {

  var prog = $(".progress-bar");

  prog.eq(0).animate({width:"50%"}, 1500)

  prog.eq(1).animate({width:"70%"}, 1500)

  prog.eq(2).animate({width:"85%"}, 1500)

});
```

We set the width in percentages individualy.

At the html code remove the `width` value we will set it in css to 0 so we can animate it properly.

Css:

```
.progress-bar {
  width:0px;
}
```

[**here**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/EVdRwj?editors=011) is the working example.

Comment: @Ganga Works pretty smoothly on my end. try other browsers might be lagging for you for some reason.

Comment: Yep i realise that 2 min after i comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the elements using `$.each()` and animate each to the value of the element's `aria-valuenow` parameter (don't actually do this in production, `aria-valuenow` is supposed to be the value *now*):

```
$(function() {
    $(".progress-bar").each(function() {
        var finalWidth = parseInt($(this).attr("aria-valuenow"));
        $(this).css("width", "0px").animate({width: finalWidth+"%"}, 1500);
    });
});
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Seems odd to me too, but his/her question includes code that does exactly that.

Comment: Point is that this progress bar are not animated by default, so i wanted to make effect of animation to this specific value .

Comment: Anyway , this code is not working  - i think because it collect px value and this particular bootstrap element require % value in width.

Comment: Thank you, yet it work quite strange. Take a look . 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKYXyx

Comment: I manage to resolve problem with that by adding $(".progress-bar").css("width", "0px"). Its good enough solution but code freeze a little bit at  start